# Round only 2 corners of a UIView in custom UITableViewCell - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I have a `UIView` in a custom `UITableViewCell` and I want to round just bottom Left and Right corners of that view. I'm doing the following, but it's not working:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

    CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: _viewForTags.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){7.0, 7.0}].CGPath;

    _viewForTags.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

I usually achieve this in usual View Controllers in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method and it works perfectly, but there's no such method when I subclass `UITableViewCell`.

Any idea how can I round 2 corners of a view in a subclassed `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: once try in cellrowatindexpath and try

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work :(

Comment: the reason it called only one time , if you scroll it does not affect , can you update your question

Comment: don't forget to set `maskToBounds` on the `CALayer` to `true` if you want it to clip the layer's contents as well as sublayers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually there is a method for that state in `UITableViewCell`. it is `layoutSubviews`

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: _im.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){7.0, 7.0}].CGPath;

    _im.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Comment: what is _im ,is it view?

Comment: it is a view that you want to round the corners.

Comment: this is a method inside the customcell class( actually it is a UIView method, you need to override it inside CustomCell class). _im is a subview you added in a cell.

Comment: Swift:
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: someView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.bottomLeft, UIRectCorner.bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 3.0, height: 3.0)).cgPath
        someView.layer.mask = maskLayer

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewDelgate's

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

method will be called overtime when cell is about to be displayed on the screen. You can have your code in this method.

Comment: Thanks for the info on that Delegate method I didn't know about. But unfortunately, it doesn't work for my case. It only does when I scroll the tableView, then it shows rounder corners, but not when table is loaded for the first time

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you put your code in wrong place. Method `awakeFromNib` is actually place where your views got initialized, and at this time _`viewForTags.bounds` gives you `CGRectZero`. You need to move your code into `setSelected:animated:` method, or give concrete `CGRect` value.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_viewForTags.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:(CGSize){7.0, 7.0}].CGPath;
    _viewForTags.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply in cellforrowatindex

```
CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: yourCustomCell.yourViewInCustomCell.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){7.0, 7.0}].CGPath;

yourCustomCell.yourViewInCustomCell.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with Swift 5 (and probably earlier):

```
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(
                         roundedRect:       myView.bounds,
                         byRoundingCorners: [topLeft, .topRight],                             
                         cornerRadii:       CGSize(width:10.0, height:10.0)
                     ).cgPath
    myView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```